# Javascript - Manipulate Array structure inside existing JSON string

Tags: javascript, json

I have a simple json in which I want to manipulate array structure and data as below , Can anyone suggest How can I do this using javascript or xpaths.

current json :-

```
{
  "pimage": [
    {
      "limage": "http://images.bestbuy.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/7306/7306011_sb.jpg",
      "timage": "http://images.bestbuy.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/7306/7306011_s.gif",
      "mimage": "http://images.bestbuy.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/7306/7306011fp.gif",
      "lfimage": "http://img.bbystatic.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/7306/7306011_sa.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

expected :- below limage key is made common and urls values from current json is kept as it is.

```
{
  "pimage": [
    {
      "limage": "http://images.bestbuy.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/7306/7306011_sb.jpg"
    },
    {
      "limage": "http://images.bestbuy.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/7306/7306011_s.gif"
    },
    {
      "limage": "http://images.bestbuy.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/7306/7306011_s.gif"
    },
    {
      "limage": "http://images.bestbuy.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/7306/7306011_s.gif"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: @NinaScholz rule ? i dint get you , can you please elaborate

Comment: how is the *current* to the *expected* mapped. a rule is not visible.

Comment: what happen to `'.../7306011_sa.jpg'` string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question feels a bit unclear, but this code will turn your object into the form you wanted:

```
var myObj = {
  "pimage": [
    {
      "limage": "http://images.bestbuy.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/7306/7306011_sb.jpg",
      "timage": "http://images.bestbuy.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/7306/7306011_s.gif",
      "mimage": "http://images.bestbuy.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/7306/7306011fp.gif",
      "lfimage": "http://img.bbystatic.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/7306/7306011_sa.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
var myFunc = function(obj) { 
  var keys = Object.keys(obj.pimage[0]);
  var newObj = {"pimage":[]};
  keys.forEach(function(k) {
    var newImg = {};
    newImg['limage'] = obj.pimage[0][k];
    newObj.pimage.push(newImg);
  });
  return newObj;
}

console.log(myFunc(myObj));
```

With more information, it the myFunc() function could be crafted a bit more robustly.

Comment: @milerbr , I used push with key value and it worked. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function Parse(ur_obj) {
   var iterate = ur_obj.pimage[0];
   var result = [];
   for(var x in iterate) {
      result.push({x:iterate[x]});
   }
   ur_obj.pimage = result;
   return ur_obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution maps every key/value pair to a seperated object.

```js
var obj = {
        "pimage": [{
            "limage": "http://images.bestbuy.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/7306/7306011_sb.jpg",
            "timage": "http://images.bestbuy.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/7306/7306011_s.gif",
            "mimage": "http://images.bestbuy.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/7306/7306011fp.gif",
            "lfimage": "http://img.bbystatic.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/7306/7306011_sa.jpg"
        }]
    };

obj.pimage = Object.keys(obj.pimage[0]).map(function (k) {
    var o = {};
    o[k] = obj.pimage[0][k];
    return o;
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(obj, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```